# Vite custom plugin transformIndexHtml hook not working during build

Tags: javascript, vite, bundler

I'm writing custom plugin in vite.js to transform my `index.html` file:

```
  return {
    name: 'html-build-plugin',
    apply: 'build',
    transformIndexHtml: {
      order: 'post',
      handler(htmlData, ctx) {
        const transformedHtml = htmlData.replace('<title>', '<title>aaa:');

        return transformedHtml;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

I'm using this plugin in my `vite.config.ts` file:

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    mode,
    build: {
      outDir: 'dist',
      sourcemap: mode === 'development' ? 'inline' : true,
      target: 'modules',
      cssCodeSplit: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scripts', 'entry.ts'),
        },
        output: {
          format: 'systemjs',
          dir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
          generatedCode: 'es2015',
          manualChunks(id: string): string {
            if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
              return 'vendor';
            }
          },
          chunkFileNames: '[name].[hash].js',
          entryFileNames: '[name].[hash].js',
          assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash][extname]',
          plugins: [
            manifestJSON.default({
              fileName: 'manifest.json',
            }),
          ],
        },
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
    },
    plugins: [HtmlBuildPlugin()],
  };
});
```

Plugin is working and hook is called only in dev mode (when I call `npx vite dev`). When I'm running build mode `npx vite build` (Vite does in fact copy my `index.html` from my public directory to dist directory) it does not. [Docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#vite-specific-hooks) states that it should work in both cases: `The context exposes the ViteDevServer instance during dev, and exposes the Rollup output bundle during build`. What am I doing wrong? I tried placing this plugin in rollup options, but it does not work either.

Comment: did you found a solution @Furman ?

Comment: @Ssh-uunen kind of - see my answer

Answer (score -1):

Just for record in case anyone would have similiar problem: In `rollupOptions` I had to add separate entrypoint for html file. It's weird and it generates additional empty javascript file, but it works.

```
rollupOptions: {
  input: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scripts', 'entry.ts'),
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
  },
```